# Android Memory Leak new Thread()

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

It's about android application memory leak of Thread object.

I didn't know yet following code cause memory leak since I started android program for 3 years.

```
Thread t = new Thread();
```

t is NOT detected by garbage collector.

**Question is how can i release local variable t from vm memory?**

I decide to experiment

I made button on my app which is conduct following code.

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
   Thread t = new Thread();
}
```

I expected local variable t will be deallocated some day.

And I executed it with debug mode and opened E-clipse DDMS perspective.

I choose my application thread on my android device(2.3.6) and clicked "update heap" button

so I can check heap size and allocated on real time.

It started with total heap size 5.445MB and allocated 2.779 MB.

And I clicked button which is produce 1000 thread objects.

It changed by heap size 5.508MB and allocated 3.058 MB.

As you know there is "Cause GC" button on DDMS perspective.

I clicked that button. But Allocated memory was still 3.058MB.

I clicked my button again to produce another 1000 thread objects.

And I clicked hopeless "Gause GC" button.

Eventually heap size was gone about 20MB and out of memory exception caused.

How can I release Thread instance object?

Comment: In most cases it is better to use an Executor instead of a thread. If you use something like a cachedThreadPool it will handle the active threads for you. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you're done using the thread, call [`interupt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29).

And I don't know if it's necessary, but it might be a good idea to set `t=null` as was suggested by Johannes.

But after you've stopped the thread, then it is up to the JVM's Garbage Collector to handle the destruction of the thread itself.

Comment: it doesn't work....  for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
     Thread t = new Thread();
     t.start();
     t.interrupt();
     t = null;
    }

Comment: Well. It really shouldn't matter. There should be no instance where you need to create 1000 threads. And creating one thread will not use up that much memory.
And the fact that you're creating so many threads might be the cause of the problem. If you were to create one, interupt it, and make it null, then chances are it would be cleared from memory. If not, then I don't believe there's anything you'd be able to do about it.

Comment: This actually fixed it for my situation where I am creating 7000 threads in about 20 minutes using an array of 12 Thread objects.  @muyoungko I notice your for loop test doesn't actually have a run or anything - perhaps that is part of the problem... calling interrupt() too soon after start()?  In my situation, I have an AtomicBoolean (array for multiple threads) that tells me thread is finished - and then I interrupt() on  the original Thread object before creating a new one in the same array slot. Memory leak disappeared with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an android device to test it on, but I would think that a Thread needs to die before it can be garbage collected in addition to not being referenced by any variable.

Try starting the threads in your loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread();
    t.start();
    t = null;
}
```